how to play video of h264 encode in the Electron
have checked and tried the following solutions and a few others:
Cannot play offline video in production electron app
Video tag in electron
Electron video cannot play
Playing local mp4 file in electron
And I've unfortunately had no success.
Thanks in advance for any help or support.
Regards
